# Android Notification plays default sound instead of Custom

Tags: android, notifications

I am trying to use Android's Notification Manager i.e. **android.app.Notification** and **android.app.NotificationManager** which works perfectly fine using the following code on my Android Device which has OS 4.4.2.
It seems they don't work properly on some older OS say 4.2.x. I see a notification pop up but the sound is default notification sound and not the one I chose, and this works fine on my device which is 4.4.2.

```
Uri alarmSound = Uri.parse("/storage/sdcard1/MyApp/Media/Sounds/fire.mp3");

NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
            inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle(notificationString);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                    (new Intent(context, NavigationMenu.class)),
                    0);

Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo_black)
                            .setContentTitle(notificationString)
                            .setContentText(notificationString)
                            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                            .setAutoCancel(true)
                            .setSound(alarmSound)
                            .build();

mNotificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification);
```

The uri is actually not hard coded and is obtained using *Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()* and the file is present at the specified location. Since this is working perfectly fine on my device and not on older one, the first thought is the issue is with OS versions, but i can't find a solution for old versions.

**Update**
So this doesn't seem to be the problem with OS since i tested it on another Android Device with OS 4.2.2 and it worked.

Still unable to dig up the cause...

Answer (score 0):

```
notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.pop);
```

add sound file into a raw folder.

Comment: issue is i cant do that since my app has the feature to download desired alert sounds and use in app.